# AttributeError: module 'vtkmodules.all' has no attribute 'vtkGDALVectorReader'

Tags: python, vtk

I'm trying to use this function `vtkGDALVectorReader` from the `vtk` library.

Everytime I try to use it, it says it doesn't exist. I've tried a few different version of vtk now and even looked at peoples code where I know this works.

I see it on the github, I see it in the docs.. why is it not working in python? I am using pip installed verison - perhaps I have to build from source?

Is there some additional step to install GDAL capabilities in VTK ??

```
import vtk
vtk.vtkGDALVectorReader()
```

Comment: Yes, enable the CGAL module when you build VTK.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal got a link to some instructions ? I'm very inexperienced at this sort of thing

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md